# Interview: draw shapes (circles & squares) until area is less than X

Tags: algorithm

I was recently asked this question at an interview and I wasn't able to solve it. I wanted to post it here and see if anyone can give me some ideas on how to approach on solving such problems.

**Question: Given positive X axis and Y axis...**

1. **Start by drawing a square of width=A (say A=1000)**
2. **Next draw a circle of maximum possible radius inside the square such that the circle touches all 4 sides of the square.**
3. **Next draw a square inside this circle such that all 4 vertices of the square are touching the circle.**
4. **Keep repeating the above process and keep drawing circles and squares alternatively until the area of the shape just drawn is < B (say B=10).**

***Write the pseudocode/logic to achive this.***

Here is a sample diagram showing what the interviewer asked (excuse the mishapen portion).

[image: Sample diagram, obviously, the question is theoretical, so don't read too much into the exact shape of my drawing]

Comment: The square's area is s^2. The circle's area is pi(s/2)^2. The next s is s/sqrt(2). To approach this kind of problem where you can easily do it manually, I'd suggest doing it manually and describing to yourself what steps you're taking.

Comment: The area of each successive square decreases by a factor of 2. So start by dividing the area of the first square by 2 until the area is less than B. Then check whether the next larger circle is still less than B. The area of the circle is PI/2 larger than the corresponding inscribed square.

Comment: Specifically where are you stuck? Perhaps finding the radius or width of the new shape? Or something more fundamental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 cases:

1. You're given width of a square the circle's area would then be 
   A = (width^2)*pi/4
2. You're given radius of a circle the square's area would then be 
   A = 2*(R^2)

In python:

```
R=0
width=1000
result=1000000 
B=10
square=True

while result > B:
    if square:
        R=width/2
        result=math.pi*(R*R)
    else:
        width=R*math.sqrt(2)
result=2*R*R
    square = not square

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a simple math problem. The basic idea is to always calculate the surface by knowing the square's side and the circle's diameter (or radius). The formulas are:

**P = a^2** for the square

**P = (D^2)/4** for the circle where D is the diameter (not radius).

The side of the first square is `a`, then this means that the diameter of the next circle is also `a`, which in turn means that the diagonal of the next square is `a`. You can use Pythagorean theorem to calculate the side of the square and you repeat this until you reach the surface which is less than the one required.

> I've not written a single line of code because the language is not specified and I think you can manage that with my idea. And on those interviews, they usually just want to see your line of thinking.